# Why is std::uninitialized_move absent?

Tags: c++, stl, c++11

The C++11 standard library includes the following related algorithms:

```
template <class InputIterator, class ForwardIterator>
  ForwardIterator uninitialized_copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                                     ForwardIterator result);

template <class ForwardIterator, class T>
  void uninitialized_fill(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last,
                          const T& x);

template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator copy(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                      OutputIterator result);

template<class ForwardIterator, class T>
  void fill(ForwardIterator first, ForwardIterator last, const T& value);

template<class InputIterator, class OutputIterator>
  OutputIterator move(InputIterator first, InputIterator last,
                      OutputIterator result);
```

There is no standard `uninitialized_move` algorithm. Is this an oversight, or by design?

If it is by design, what is the rationale?

Comment: The same goes for `std::move_if()` and `std::move_n()`, BTW.

Comment: Note that `std::uninitialized_move` appeared in **C++17**. Unfortunately, there is no `std::uninitialized_move_if_noexcept`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can get the effect of an `uninitialized_move` with `uninitialized_copy` and move iterators:

```
std::uninitialized_copy(std::make_move_iterator(first),
                        std::make_move_iterator(last),
                        out);
```

`std::move` exists even though it can also be implemented with `std::copy` and move iterators, because the committee anticipated its use to be frequent and decided to provide it as a convenience function [[1]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1771.html)[[2]](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1860.html).

Comment: Actually it is by design.  The only reason the move/move_backward algorithms were specified is because of the anticipated frequency of their use (they are convenience functions).  This is documented in http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1771.html and http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2005/n1860.html